# Displaying whether a foreign key is set when doing a left join, but still showing distinct records at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Product Table - Columns: Id, ProductName, ProductCategoryId
ProductCategory Table - Columns: Id, CategoryName

I want to list all of the distinct categories, but have an InUse column that says whether the category is set to a product or not.

**Here is my query:**

```
select pc.*, CASE WHEN p.Id IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as InUse
from ProductCategory pc
left outer join Product p on pc.Id = p.ProductCategoryId
group by pc.Id, pc.CategoryName
```

**However, I am unsure how to select a column like the following:**

```
CASE WHEN p.Id IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
```

The issue is that it wants me to now group by p.Id which will be a problem because then I will get more records than I want in my listing. Lets say a category is being used for several products I still only want it to show once in the list.

Comment: Why do you do a GROUP BY when you have no aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, SUM, COUNT)? Also the general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh But would `SELECT pc.*` by itself fly?  The table only has the two columns on which he is grouping.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes it would, but why not do SELECT DISTINCT instead in that case?

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` and then you can leave your `CASE` statement as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an aggregate function, like `MAX`:

```
CASE WHEN MAX(p.Id) IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as InUse
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select pc.*,
CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Product p WHERE pc.Id = p.ProductCategoryId ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as InUse
from ProductCategory pc
```